# Convergence in distribution of sum of two random sequence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem

Let $\{(x_i,y_i)\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of iid random variables, with $E|x_i|<\infty$, $E(y_i)=0$, and $E(x_iy_i)=0$. Both $y_i$ and $x_iy_i$ have finite second moment. And let

$$
a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i, \quad b_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i, \quad\text{and}\quad c_n = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i.
$$

By LLN, CLT, and Slutsky's theorem, $a_n\overset{d}{\to}N(0,E(x_i^2y_i^2))$, $b_nc_n\overset{d}{\to}N(0,E(x_i)^2E(y_i^2))$.

My question is, is it possible to obtain the limiting distribution of $a_n-b_nc_n$? Thanks.

**My thinking:** We can rewrite $b_nc_n$ as $\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$, which is $o_p(1)O_p(1)=o_p(1)$, so $a_n-b_nc_n = a_n + o_p(1)$ has the same limiting distribution as $a_n$. But I'm no so sure whether this argument is correct.

Comment: Well, in light of LLN, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$ need not be $\mathcal{O}_p(1)$, especially when $\mathbf{E}[x_i]\neq 0$. I suggest you to consider the decomposition $$a_n -b_n c_n = (a_n - \mathbf{E}[x_1] b_n) + (\mathbf{E}[x_1] - c_n) b_n. $$

Comment: @SangchulLee, sorry, I should add a condtion that $x_i$ also has finite second moment. Then by CLT, $\sum_ix_i/\sqrt{n}\overset{d}{\to}N(E(x_i),E(x_i^2))$, does this suffice to guarantee $\sum_ix_i/\sqrt{n}$ is $O_p(1)$? I mean any random variable having a limiting distribution is $O_p(1)$.

Comment: Note that $$\mathbf{E}\biggl[\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\biggr] = \sqrt{n}\mathbf{E}[x_1] $$ and this diverges as $n\to\infty$ unless $\mathbf{E}[x_1]=0$. What is true is that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\mathbf{E}[x_1]) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{d} \mathcal{N}(0,\mathbf{Var}(x_1)).$$

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks:) I have applied CLT incorrectly.